# Can recipient variables be used to conditionally render sections

Tags: mailgun

I am trying to render sections of a template depending on recipient variables.

I am able to control sections if I reference the normal mailgun variables.

Given the following template

```
{{name}}

{{#A}}
A - {{name}}
{{/A}}

{{#B}}
B - {{name}}
{{/B}}
```

To make this template render A or B, I pass A and B in

```
h:X-Mailgun-Variables='{"A":"true" ,"name": "My Name"}'
```

Is it possible for the template to render A or B from recipient variables in the case of batch sending, something like this where recipient variables are

```
h:X-Mailgun-Recipient-Variables='{"a@email.com":{ "A":"true", "a":"A value"}, 
"b@email.com":{ "B":"true", "b":"B value"}}
```

and the template is something like this

```
{{#%recipient.A%}}
A - %recipient.a%
{{/%recipient.A%}}

{{#%recipient.B%}}
B - %recipient.b%
{{/%recipient.B%}}
```

Is something like this possible ?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Did you mean {{#if %recipient.A%}} and {{/if}} instead?
However, I am trying to use batch recipient variables as conditional values as well, and Mailgun fails to parse the template (even when doing it the way I suggested as documented by Handlebar syntax)

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am trying to do the same...

Comment: I have not been able to find a way to do this, though I have stopped looking for a while now. I think I ended up setting a value to something like 'No value set' or something to that affect rather than not rendering the section altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might have used the `The if block helper` described [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#templates).